# Subresource Integrity: How to show only warning but not block resource?

Tags: html, subresource-integrity

I would like to make a **soft integration** for **Subresource Integrity** attributes, so be sure that I did not break the application, **but only to show a warning** that I need to fix some places.

Is there an option to do so?

Comment: Related post - [How can I make sure that my JavaScript files delivered over a CDN are not altered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38700923/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Secure approach

If you need some kind of flexibility, then you should use a [fallback mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40408636/handling-load-error-within-subresource-integrity-check) - loading required resource from another URL. Probability that two different URL's will be hacked at the same time is a lot smaller compared to hacking just one resource. Fallback doesn't violate site security, because you *must* trust your known-good sources which you use in your code. If your resource is a Javascript - you can use a [noncanonical-src](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-SRI-20140318/#fallback-1) attribute for a fallback too.

### Insecure approach

Now, if you really, really want a user to break server and/or client security by forcing compromised resource load - at least ask a user if he/she takes responsibility by doing so. Of course this will still be a stupid thing, it's like asking "*Would you like to run a virus in your computer ?*". I bet nobody would like to say YES. Anyway, here is the code, which does asking these type of questions:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function loadResource(path) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var cs = CryptoJS.SHA256(this.responseText);
        if (btoa(cs) == 'NjBiMTllNWRhNmE5MjM0ZmY5MjIwNjY4YTVlYzExMjVjMTU3YTI2ODUxMzI1NjE4OGVlODBmMmQyYzhkOGQzNg==' ||
            confirm('Bootstrap is NOT the latest version 4.3.1, load anyway ?')
           ) {
          var link = document.createElement('link');
          link.rel = "stylesheet";
          link.href = path;
          document.head.appendChild(link);
        }
        else {
           var err = document.getElementById('error');
           err.title = "Component version error !";
           err.innerHTML = '&nbsp;⚠️';
        }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", path, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }

  loadResource(
              //'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' // newest boostrap
              'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css' // old legacy
              );
  </script>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gdmw8z5n/)

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend only displaying warnings when the SRI-Hashes don't match. When see the warning as a User, it's already too late and potentially malicious scripts were executed on your machine.

However, you can implement your desired behaviour using the [`ServiceWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)-API and something like `<script data-integrity="xxxxxxxx">`. For that, you'd want to:

1. Register a new `ServiceWorker`
2. Listen to the `fetch` event
3. [`[Client.postMessage]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) the targetURL to your Parent
4. Get script integrity hash by targetURL `$('script[src=event.data.targetURL]').attr('data-integrity')` 
   and push it into the client using [`Worker.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage)
5. hash the response using e.G. [`cryptojs.sha256`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)
6. match the hashes inside the worker
7. If the hashes match, return the response. If they don't match, return the response and use `Client.postMessage` again to trigger a warning.